# How to add xaml code in c# comment?

Tags: c#, xaml, xml-documentation

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks
/// 
/// </remarks>
```

How to add xaml code in above comment, avoiding code parser to create links that do not exist (CTRL + Click messages)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Standard XML escaping

   `/// &lt;TextBlock Text=&quot;Hello World!&quot;/&gt;`
2. CDATA sections

   `/// <![CDATA[<TextBlock Text="Hello World!"/>]]>`

With the first option, Visual Studio Intellisense will properly show the unescaped XML sequence.

Answer (score 6):

In XAML view, put some XAML you want to use as comment

Then  surround it with

```
<!-- #region XAML Snippet -->
<StackPanel>
  <Button Content="Click me, I do nothing!" />
</StackPanel>
<!-- #endregion -->
```

Note: i put this in a MainWindow.xaml file, but it can be any XAML file.

Now in C#, to use this as a comment:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <code source="MyProject.Namespace/MainWindow.xaml" region="XAML snippet" lang="XAML" title="A linked *.xaml file treated as XAML"/>
/// </example>
```

SandCastle understands this syntax, and will generate appropriate documentation (like in MSDN), however this won't show up on intellisense.

You could format a regular `<summary>` body with `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of `< >` signs in order to mimic XAML syntax, but that's going to be a pain.

Answer (score 2):

Use CDATA tags?

```
/// <summary>
/// <![CDATA[<StackPanel />]]>
/// </summary>
```

Note: this won't appear in Intellisense so if that is a requirement this method won't work for your scenario.

Why do you want to add XAML into a code file, though?

Comment: I am creating a behavior in c#, so I want to put explanation how it is this behavior used in xaml code.